# './docker-compose.yml', service must be a mapping, not a NoneType

Tags: docker, yaml, docker-compose

When I ran: `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=zk_test docker-compose up`, I got error saying

> "ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service must be a mapping, not
>   a NoneType.".

This is my yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
zoo1:
image: zookeeper
restart: always
container_name: zoo1
ports:
- "2181:2181"
environment:
ZOO_MY_ID: 1
ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888

zoo2:
image: zookeeper
restart: always
container_name: zoo2
ports:
- "2182:2181"
environment:
ZOO_MY_ID: 2
ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888

zoo3:
image: zookeeper
restart: always
container_name: zoo3
ports:
- "2183:2181"
environment:
ZOO_MY_ID: 3
ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888
```

Sample Image:

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Without a properly formatted question this is really hard to answer why your compose file is not working. I was able to take the example from https://hub.docker.com/_/zookeeper/ and setup this up without issue.

Answer (score 80):

YAML is indentation dependent. This

```
services:
zoo1:
```

is a mapping with two keys that both map to `null` (i.e. `None` in Python).

Whereas:

```
services:
   zoo1:
```

is a mapping nested in a mapping. The key 'services' has as value a mapping with key `zoo1` (which again has a value `null`).

Comment: This solved my problem. I was having issues with the indentation before so I removed all indentations. And then I encountered another problem and this answer solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

```yaml
version: '2'                                                                    
services:                                                                          
  autodiscovery:                                                                   
  build: ./autodiscovery/                                                          
  mem_limit: 128m                                                                  
  expose:                                                                          
    - 53                                                                           
    - 8300                                                                         
    - 8301                                                                         
    - 8302                                                                         
    - 8400                                                                         
    - 8500                                                                         
  ports:                                                                           
    - 8500:8500                                                                    
  dns:                                                                             
    - 127.0.0.1
```

just put one space. before.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a dash at the beginning of each environment line, in addition to indentation, seems to be a requirement. It did when using Portainer to deploy at least i.e.

```
    services:
      zoo1:
        image: zookeeper
        restart: always
        container_name: zoo1
        ports:
          - "2181:2181"
        environment:
          - ZOO_MY_ID: 1
          - ZOO_SERVER: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888
```

Answer (score -1):

To solve the error message, simply put the "ports:" statement under the "services:" code block, 1 or 2 tab spaces will be enough for this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).