# ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service 'build' must be a mapping not a string

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am working on a php docker application.Am facing an error while trying 
docker-compose up command. Trying to connect a php application to mysql.

My docker compose file :-

```
 version: '2'
 services:
 web:
 container_name: modeloPHP5.4-Apache
 build: .
 ports:
 — 8889:80

 volumes:
 — ./www:/var/www/html

 links:
 — db

 db:
 container_name: modeloMySQL
 build:
 context: ./
 dockerfile: DockerfileDB
 volumes:
 — /var/lib/mysql

 ports:
 — 3307:3306

 environment:

 MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
 MYSQL_USER: user
 MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
 MYSQL_DATABASE: db_test
```

Comment: Am facing this error now..

Unsupported config option for services.environment: 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD'
Unsupported config option for services.db: 'dockerfile'
Thanks..

Comment: Those errors are related with your indentation again. You may use [docker-compose config](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/config/) to check the syntax of your compose file. Also you could update your current Docker compose file in your question so you can track what you have already fixed.

Comment: Ok, Thank you.........

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Docker compose files are YAML files that require indentation, due to a wrong indentation in your compose file, Docker thinks that build is a service declaration. You've a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452448/docker-compose-yml-service-must-be-a-mapping-not-a-nonetype) and you can follow an example in Docker docs to check [how the indentation works](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build).

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, let me check !

Comment: Am facing this error now? Unsupported config option for services.environment: 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD'
Unsupported config option for services.db: 'dockerfile'
Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

docker-compose file is using the YAML format, so you must check every space, line, new line and other syntax is correct in yaml format. 
you can use [yaml parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) to help you to check docker-compose file.

```
version: '2'

services:
 web:
  container_name: modeloPHP5.4-Apache
  build: .
  ports:
       - 8889:80
  volumes:
         - ./www:/var/www/html
  links:
       - db

 db:
  container_name: modeloMySQL
  build:
  context: ./
  dockerfile: DockerfileDB
  volumes:
         - /var/lib/mysql
  ports:
       - 3307:3306
  environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
  MYSQL_USER: user
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
  MYSQL_DATABASE: db_test
```

Comment: E: Unable to locate package libicu-dev
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y libicu-dev' returned a non-zero code: 100

Comment: that error is not from docker-compose file but your image, your image can not download / install  libicu-dev  package

Comment: As Muh says once that you've solved your indentation problem in your file now you have a problem with the image building (package libicu-dev failed to install).