# docker-compose.yml C# .net 5 console app, exception service must be a mapping

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose, yaml, .net-5

I created a .net5 C# console app from template. Then added docker-compose by Add -> container orchestration support -> docker-compose.

Generated Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1.csproj", "ConsoleApp1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ConsoleApp1"
RUN dotnet build "ConsoleApp1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ConsoleApp1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ConsoleApp1.dll"]
```

Generated docker-compose

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  consoleapp1:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}consoleapp1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ConsoleApp1/Dockerfile
```

When I tried to run this example I gon a message "**services.consoleapp1 must be a mapping**".

Is there a way I can run console app in docker-compose?

Comment: Can you check the indentation of the `docker-compose.yaml`? Might be this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43460549/1974021

Comment: I checked it. 2 spaces on consoleapp1 row, 4 on image and build rows, 6 on context and dockerfile rows. Looks like it's ok.

Comment: hmm odd. I tried to create a simple console app and instead of using the generated one. paste yours and its working fine. I've tried in windows container btw

Comment: The problem was really odd. Didn't expect problem inside another file. Maybe problem is in my VS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in docker-compose.override.yml

Generated file was

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  consoleapp1:
```

Because "**consoleapp1:**" is empty I catched the error.

I removed services part and it's working now.