# validating docker-compose.yml: services must be a mapping

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin

i was working on my docker config with postgresql and pgadmin, and i had the next lines on the visual studio code (i investigated and the web says to put these):

```
version: '3.8'

services:

postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - "5432:5432"
environment:
    - DATABASE_HOST=127.0.0.1
    - POSTGRES_USER=root
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
    - POSTGRES_DB=root

pgadmin:
  image: dpage/pgadmin4
  environment:
    PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: "cindyrid1305@gmail.com"
    PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: "admin"
  ports:
     - "80:80"  
  depends_on:
    - postgres
```

i opened in the same visual studio a terminal and wrote docker-compose up:

`PS C:\Users\Izzy\OneDrive\Documentos\webproject> docker-compose up`

and got this:

`validating C:\Users\Izzy\OneDrive\Documentos\webproject\docker-compose.yml: services must be a mapping`

i expect that writing the docker-compose line start downloading and configurating everything as i asked for. after that download, is supposed i can use pgadmin with postgresql

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['./docker-compose.yml', service must be a mapping, not a NoneType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452448/docker-compose-yml-service-must-be-a-mapping-not-a-nonetype)

Comment: I tried with the space, but it didn't work

Comment: indentation matters in yaml see [learn yaml in y minutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/). All your services must be indented correctly under the `services:` entry.

Answer (score 0):

It's already answered in comments that it's an issue with indentation, adding the correct configuration with indentation

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=127.0.0.1
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - POSTGRES_DB=root

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: "cindyrid1305@gmail.com"
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: "admin"
    ports:
      - "80:80"  
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

Note the difference, `postgres` and `pgadmin` are service, so there is one indentation from services.

Similarly image/environment are sub heading of postgres and pgadmin so there is another indentation.

I will recommend you reading about [yaml](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/yaml-tutorial-everything-you-need-get-started) if you're not already familiar with it.